# Getting associated/corresponding row without duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE (giver = '%d' OR taker = '%d')
```

I have a table called conversations which has two notable columns giver and taker. I have a numeric variable (this is either the value of a giver or taker, I don't know which hence this problem) which I'd like to pass to a MySQLi query to get the associated/corresponding giver or taker row.

How can the above query be amended to do such a thing? Presently it produces duplicates - GROUP BY does not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont understand quite well,
you want the other row ?
edit: select giver or taker not both, union supress double values

```
SELECT giver,*(...except taker column )   FROM conversations WHERE giver = '%d' 
union 
SELECT taker,* (...except giver column)  FROM conversations WHERE taker = '%d'
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to word it, but yes I want the other row. Your above query suggests I know both giver and taker, but I just have 1.

Comment: if your table is (one row) : giver1|taker1|....| , etc, last row giverN| takerN| ... you want giver or taker, the other row will be the row taker corresponding to giver or the row taker corresponding to giver

Comment: I see, I have updated my question - maybe that helps. :/